# What (specifically) happens when you have Win7 move default user folders?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, mklink

In C:\Users\Myself, I right-click on Videos folder, select "location" tab, click "Move" button, and enter "D:\Videos" as new location; then confirm that this location is added to the Videos library (and that C:\Users\Myself\Videos has been removed).

Now Explorer does not show any visible "Video" folder in C:\Users\Myself, even with hidden files shown. Nonetheless, entering C:\Users\Myself\Videos in Explorer jumps to D:\Videos.

I open CMD window and change to C:\Users\Myself directory. **DIR /A** shows nothing at all named Videos. **CD C:\Users\Myself\Videos** returns an error.

What the heck is going on? I assumed that Windows would move the Videos folder by placing a junction or symbolic link in C:\Users\Myself, but that doesn't seem to be what it's actually doing. What exactly is windows doing?

Comment: If you want a junction/symbolic link you would need to create that yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to be the case. But right now I'm trying to understand what Windows _actually does_ when you tell it to change the location of one of the default User folders.